# MS-Graph-Sdk-DotNet: How to send multiple chunk requests at the same time when uploading a large file?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

After creating an upload session, I'm uploading the content of a large file by sending chunk requests. However, sending a request one at a time takes a relatively long time to upload the entire content of the file.

Is it possible to send multiple chunk requests at the same time by using multithreading?

I tried using [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.8), but it doesn't work.

```cs
int maxSizeChunk = 320 * 1024 * 4;
ChunkedUploadProvider uploadProvider = new ChunkedUploadProvider(uploadSession, client, ms, maxSizeChunk);
IEnumerable<UploadChunkRequest> chunkRequests = uploadProvider.GetUploadChunkRequests();
List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[maxSizeChunk];

//  How to send multiple requests at once?
foreach (UploadChunkRequest request in chunkRequests)
{
     UploadChunkResult result = await uploadProvider.GetChunkRequestResponseAsync(request, readBuffer, exceptions);

     if (result.UploadSucceeded)
         uploadedFile = result.ItemResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can upload via multiple streams at the same time.

Per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0):

> The fragments of the file must be uploaded sequentially in order. Uploading fragments out of order will result in an error.